# Getting UPLOAD_ERR_PARTIAL when uploading images on localhost

Tags: php, html, image, forms, localhost

I'm working on a simple html form to upload an image, then save it on a directory situated on my localhost.

```
<form action="<?php echo htmlspecialchars($_SERVER['PHP_SELF']);?>" enctype="multipart/form-data" method="post">
<label for="img">Pick a picture</label>
<input id="img" type="file" name="image">
<input type="submit" name="imageProfil" value="Upload the image">
</form>
```

However, when I handle the image, while checking errors (in $_FILES['image']['errors'], I'm getting an error 3, which means the file has only been partially uploaded.

Moreover, each time I upload a file, I'm not getting any response after the first response (where the exception is thrown at me). I've done all the error checking, I did put the enctype="multipart/form-data" on my form, and I'm basically clueless right here.

Thank you for your time.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to check your `php.ini` configuration. If your upload is constantly being interrupted, you either need to increase the [maximum upload size](https://www.php.net/manual/en/ini.core.php#ini.upload-max-filesize) or the [maximum execution time](https://www.php.net/manual/en/info.configuration.php#ini.max-execution-time). Check these variables:

```
post_max_size
upload_max_filesize
max_execution_time
memory_limit
```

You can either increase these values in your PHP configuration file or increase in your script using the [ini_set](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.ini-set.php) function.

Comment: Just checked those variables on my php.ini files, and they're respectively at 8M, 2M and 30[seconds], which is way above the image I'm trying to upload, which is 468kB. I checked the request I'm sending, and it is indeed 468kB wide, so way less than my server would refuse.

Comment: I've did a little digging on the internet and it's either the configurations, or the user cancelling the upload.

Comment: Well, it do seems like it's linked to the size of the image I'm sending, since I tried with a smaller image (27kb), and the script worked ! However, I'm supposed to have an exception thrown when the file is too big, and the server is not supposed to stop responding when I send a too big file ! Thanks for your help, anyway !

Answer (score 0):

I also got the `UPLOAD_ERR_PARTIAL` error, and the variables `post_max_size`, `upload_max_filesize` and `max_execution_time` were set correctly. I then tried to **upload a very small file** (2 Byte), as [suggested by *Kirogo*](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30425142/getting-upload-err-partial-when-uploading-images-on-localhost#comment48935969_30425169), and I got the following warnings:

```
Warning: move_uploaded_file(files/myfile.txt): failed to open stream: Permission denied [...]
Warning: move_uploaded_file(): Unable to move '/tmp/phps8Jdwt' to 'files/myfile.txt' [...]
```

After fixing the file/directory permissions on the server, the upload worked again.